# Tab order incorrect for search page

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a page that returns search results in a layout with a similar look and feel to a google page. When the results are returned, the search field has focus. I would like to be able to tab directly to the search results.

my search field has tabIndex = -1. I have assigned the  element in my returned search results with an ascending tabIndex, starting with the first.

However, when I tab in the results page it doesn't go to the first search result, it goes to another area of the page. No other elements beside the search box and these  elements even have the tabIndex attribute.

Can anyone help me understand what i'm doing wrong here? I am viewing these results in Chrome. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see if you can avoid using anything beyond `tabindex=0` and `tabindex=-1`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

If you need them in a specific order (which it doesn't sound like you do), restructuring the DOM is the better way to do that.  Then just putting `tabindex=0` on everything that should be tabbable to seems to be the best advice

Comment: I've been reading more about this and I found that, so i tried just adding these elements as the only ones with TabIndex, and they all have 0 now, but STILL the other element is getting first tab order. this is so weird.

also, this statement:
*Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so will make it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content.*
is hilarious because it comes right before they explain how to use values > 0 LOL

i'll look into rearranging with DOM? i'm not sure that's an option